# TfidfVectorizer vs. definition of tf-idf

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tf-idf

For a tutorial, I want to implement manually what the `TfidfVectorizer` is doing, just to show what's going on in the background. In this [Stack Overflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36966019/how-aretf-idf-calculated-by-the-scikit-learn-tfidfvectorizer) I found how the `TfidfVectorizer` works. With this, it was straightforward to implement it in a naive manner, and with the correct parameter settings for the vectorizer, the output is indeed the same. All good.

However, now I'm a bit confused: The `TfidfVectorizer` calculates the term frequency `tf` using the `CountVevtorizer`. That means `tf` is just an integer representing the number of occurrences of a term in a document. But usually the term frequency `tf(t,d)` of term `t` in a document `d` is defined as:

```
tf(t,d) = (#occurrences of t in d) / (#terms in d)
```

So the term frequency is a value between 0 and 1.

How does this fit together? Why is using the `TfidfVectorizer` the term count and not the (normalized) frequency according to the definition. I assume it's no a big deal but I would to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, TfidfVectorizer using as next construction:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
features = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
data = ['string1', 'string2', 'string3', 'string4', 'string5']
tfidfve = TfidfVectorizer()
tfidfve.fit_transform(data, features)
```