# What is `idf_` of sklearns TfidfVectorizer?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tf-idf, tfidfvectorizer

I thought that `.idf_` is the [inverse document frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf#Inverse_document_frequency_2), meaning it would be

```
idf_(t) = log( N/ D(t)) with N=Documents in the corpus and D(t)=number of documents which have the term t
```

So for the two documents

> ["foo bar bar ist cool und so weiter", "Ich habe hier nichts so gesagt"]

I would have expeced for everything a value of `0.69 = math.log( 2 / 1)` and for one a value of `0 = math.log(2 / 2)`.

But sklearn seems to use it differently because I get `1.406` and `1.0`.

### MVCE

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
transformer = TfidfVectorizer()
transformer.fit(["foo bar bar ist cool und so weiter", "Ich habe hier nichts so gesagt"])
print(transformer.vocabulary_)
print(transformer.idf_)
```

This gives

```
{'foo': 2, 'bar': 0, 'ist': 7, 'cool': 1, 'und': 10, 'so': 9, 'weiter': 11, 'ich': 6, 'habe': 4, 'hier': 5, 'nichts': 8, 'gesagt': 3}

[1.40546511 1.40546511 1.40546511 1.40546511 1.40546511 1.40546511
 1.40546511 1.40546511 1.40546511 1.         1.40546511 1.40546511]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36966019/how-aretf-idf-calculated-by-the-scikit-learn-tfidfvectorizer this should answer your question.

Comment: @ToodlePip Thank you! However, I still can't get `1.406` with that ... maybe I missunderstood the answers?